# The dplyr filter doesn't seem to work in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, filter, dplyr

I have many columns where in all I want to get rid of 3 specific values. I wanted to do it in a for loop. But for some reason it does not work and I can't figure out why. Here is the function:

```
for (i in colnames(df1)){
    z <- as.name(i)
    df1 <- df1 %>% filter(z != "Refusal") %>% filter(z != "Don't know") %>%  filter(z != "No answer")
}
```

I know that variable z is not necessary, but I hoped that it may help. It didn't.

And here is the full example with code for every column. This works but is rather annoying sollution

```
df1 <- data.frame(country = df$cntry, gender = df$gndr, pplfair = df$pplfair,
                  gincdif = df$gincdif, happy = df$happy, sclmeet = df$sclmeet,
                  inprdsc = df$inprdsc, sclat = df$sclact, rlgbg = df$rlgblg, 
                  dfincac = df$dfincac, sblazy = df$sblazy, eduyrs = df$eduyrs,
                  imprich = df$imprich, iprspot = df$iprspot, impfun = df$impfun)

##Wrangling data

###from data removing no answer, don't know, refusal
df1 <- df1 %>% filter(pplfair != "Refusal") %>% filter(pplfair != "Don't know") %>%  filter(pplfair != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(gincdif != "Refusal") %>% filter(gincdif != "Don't know") %>%  filter(gincdif != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(happy != "Refusal") %>% filter(happy != "Don't know") %>%  filter(happy != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(sclmeet != "Refusal") %>% filter(sclmeet != "Don't know") %>%  filter(sclmeet != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(inprdsc != "Refusal") %>% filter(inprdsc != "Don't know") %>%  filter(inprdsc != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(sclat != "Refusal") %>% filter(sclat != "Don't know") %>%  filter(sclat != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(rlgbg != "Refusal") %>% filter(rlgbg != "Don't know") %>%  filter(rlgbg != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(dfincac != "Refusal") %>% filter(dfincac != "Don't know") %>%  filter(dfincac != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(sblazy != "Refusal") %>% filter(sblazy != "Don't know") %>%  filter(sblazy != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(eduyrs != "Refusal") %>% filter(eduyrs != "Don't know") %>%  filter(eduyrs != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(imprich != "Refusal") %>% filter(imprich != "Don't know") %>%  filter(imprich != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(iprspot != "Refusal") %>% filter(iprspot != "Don't know") %>%  filter(iprspot != "No answer")

df1 <- df1 %>% filter(impfun != "Refusal") %>% filter(impfun != "Don't know") %>%  filter(impfun != "No answer")
```

I would be really grateful for any advice.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. YOu need to splice the name into the filter. Use `filter(!!z != "Don't know")` for example where ever you are trying to use `z` in the filter.

Answer (score 3):

OP's code can be simplified a lot using `filter_all` and `%in%`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(!(. %in% c("Refusal", "Don't know", "No answer"))))
```

or with `filter_at` if it's a subset of all columns:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter_at(vars(varnames), any_vars(!(. %in% c("Refusal", "Don't know", "No answer"))))
```